# Formatting of JSON file

Tags: python, json, pandas, formatting, csvtojson

Can we convert the highlighted **INTEGER** values to **STRING** value (refer below link)?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JbLQ.png

CODE

```
filename = "newsample2.csv"
jsonFileName = "myjson2.json"


import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv ('newsample2.csv')

df.to_json('myjson2.json', indent=4)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like this.

```
import pandas as pd

filename = "newsample2.csv"
jsonFileName = "myjson2.json"
df = pd.read_csv ('newsample2.csv')
df['index'] = df.index
df.to_json('myjson2.json', indent=4)
print(df)
```

This will take indices of your data and store them in the `index` column, so they will become a part of your data.